# ¿Cómo quito el borde del JScrollPanel?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un problema, no logro saber que es, ese borde que aparece en la imagen , creo saber que es un jScrollPanel ya que agregue uno al panel, por favor help!

Y si es ASÍ, por favor dígame como eliminar ese borde, GRACIAS!

Comment: Ya probaste agregándole un borde vacío? `sp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());`

Comment: Graaaaaacias brooo!!!, eres lo máximo :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más fácil de sobreescribir la rutina por defecto para pintar bordes de algunos componentes es remplazarlo por otro borde que no pinte nada.

Tal es el caso del siguiente método [createEmptyBorder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html#createEmptyBorder()) de la clase `javax.swing.BorderFactory`

```
sp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```

Comment: gracias hermano, :D personas como tu si valen oro!!